# Writing conditionals with moment js

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, momentjs

Having some difficulty finding answers on how to do this.

`date.text("Today's date is: " + moment().format("dddd MMM Do YY, h:mm a"));`

Is what I am using to display the current time on the page. I am aiming to change some css depending on the time of day. I can't find a good example of how to do this. Ideally if it is after say 1PM the CSS would change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const now = new Date();
const hours = now.getHours();
const span = document.querySelector("span");

let color;
if (hours > 6)
  color = "red";
else if (hours > 12)
  color = "yellow";
else if (hours > 16)
  color = "blue";
else color = "green";

span.innerHTML = now.toDateString(); // you can use moment here or anything
span.style.color = color;
```

```html
<div>
  Today's date is: <span></span>
</div>
```

Or you can use classes with style and assign those classes to the element.
Hopefully this looks clear to you.